# How to put some text over images side by side (inline-block)

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS by my onw, and already spent some hours on this, without solution...

I need to put a text over a image, but there is two images in the same line (inline-block). Please, see my code (example):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .payrow { display:inline-block; width:100%; margin-bottom:14px; text-align:center; }
    .paybtn { display:inline-block; margin:0 10px 0 10px; text-align:center; }
    .paybtn img { width:250px; height:120px; margin:3px; border:0; filter:alpha(opacity=80); opacity:.80; }
    .paybtn a:hover img { filter:alpha(opacity=100); opacity:1; }
    .vtotal { font:bold 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#7A7A7A; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="payrow">
    <div class="paybtn">
      <a href="pay.asp?d=1"><img src="paybtn1.gif" alt="PayPal1"></a>
      <div class="vtotal">Total: U$ 510.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="paybtn">
      <a href="pay.asp?d=2"><img src="paybtn2.gif" alt="PayPal2"></a>
      <div class="vtotal">Total: U$ 580.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result of my code:

[image]

And this is what I really want:

[image]

Please, can someone give me an idea of what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way would be negative margins, @Gaby already answered. However, a better way would be to separate out the actual image portion (PayPal logo, credit card logos) as an image, and then draw the box border and background gradient using CSS, so that the text is actually within that box. This would be useful in cases where the text may get longer, or you end up wanting to add more to the box later, and you wouldn't have to increase the image size. It's not scalable if the box border and gradient are part of the image.

Comment: Thank you @setek. You are right, this is the better way, but the page will have only few images like this, so there is no problem to use then. For now I am looking for the easier way... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use negative margins

```
.vtotal { 
    font:bold 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color:#7A7A7A; 
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-40px; /*adjust the pixels accordingly*/
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5fxRf/

Comment: Hummm... good idea @Gaby, thank you! The only problem is the cursor looses it pointer when is over the text...

Comment: @Paruba indeed.. you could include the `.vtotal` element inside the link, or you could add a `cursor:pointer;` to its CSS ..